# UInavigatioController custom animation shows white background iphone

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller, core-animation

I want to implement custom animation in uinavigation controller.
I have done it with

```
 CATransition* transition = [CATransition animation];
    transition.duration = 0.20f;
transition.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseIn];
    transition.type = kCATransitionMoveIn;
    transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromTop;
    [self.navigationController.view.layer addAnimation:transition
                                                forKey:kCATransition];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:NO];
```

But it shows a white bacground when the view controller pops up.How can I remove it
I cant use presentmodelviewcontroller right now because of some issues

Comment: Do you have your main `window` set with a white background?

Comment: my window's background color is black

Answer (score 0):

i am not telling you to do this way., but you can also try this kind of way.,.,

```
view2 *vw2=[[view2 alloc]initWithNibName:@"view2" bundle:nil];
[UIView beginAnimations:@"View Flip" context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.80];
[UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];

[UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight 
                       forView:self.navigationController.view cache:NO];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:vw2 animated:NO];

//    [self.navigationController pushViewController:aboutShowViewController animated:YES];
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

or

```
CATransition *transition = [CATransition animation];
transition.duration = 1.0f;
transition.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
transition.type = kCATransitionFade;

[self.navigationController.view.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:nil];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:vw2 animated:NO];
```

it may help you a bit.,.

i am learning.,.,.

Comment: You can't do a "move in from top" transition using the `UIViewAnimationTransition` enum.